# Scheme: + is not a procedure?

Tags: scheme, r5rs

I'm trying to learn scheme (more specifically R5RS), and I want to define a procedure that takes as input a list with 3 elements, for example: '(5 + 2),
where the middle argument always is an operator, and the 1st and 3rd are always operands.

Examples:

```
(proc-mid '(1 + 2))
--> 3
(proc-mid '(1 list 2))
--> (1 2)
(proc-mid '(20 * 5))
--> 100
```

My code so far is this:

```
(define (proc-mid exp)
    (define proc (cadr exp))
    (proc (car exp) cddr exp))
```

However, I get an error saying:

```
    application: not a procedure;
     expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
      given: +
      arguments...:
```

My question is then, why is + not evaluated as a procedure?

Answer (score 2):

When Scheme evaluates `(+ a b)` it evaluates the operand `+` and it will hopefully have a procedure value, then `a` and `b` which both perhaps should evaluate to numeric values. Then `apply` will apply the result of `+` with the result of the operands.

The quoted expression `'(+ a b)` does not evaluate it's argument. Thus `+` does not get evaluated to a procedure and `a` and `b` gets not evaluated to numbers. The value is just the list `(+ a b)`. If you were to make this with `list` you'd do `(list '+ 'a 'b)`. If you do `(list + a b)` you get the 3 variables evaluated and get something like `(#<system-procedure:+> 2 3)` back.

The quoted expression `'(+ 2 3)` is special since you have numeric literals and they are self evaluating, but `+` is still a symbol and not the evaluated variable that look the same because quote does not evaluate it's argument.

`(apply '+ '(2 3))` won't work since `+` in not a procedure.

You should perhaps map your primitives to the actual procedures?

```
;; assoc between symbols and their corresponding procedure value
(define PROCS `((+ . ,+) (* . ,*)))

(define (get-proc symbol)
  (let ((match (assq symbol PROCS)))
    (if match
        (cdr match)
        symbol)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case `+` is a [symbol](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html) since

```
'(element1 element2 ... elementn)
```

will turn text(non-numbers/boolean etc.) into symbols.

```
(define l1 '(1 a #f +))

(symbol? (car l1))
(symbol? (cadr l1))
(symbol? (caddr l1))
(symbol? (cadddr l1))
```

> #f
>
> #t
>
> #f
>
> #t

You can use `eval` carefully to evaluate the text like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558746/operations-using-list-elements/48558984#48558984):

```
(eval '(+ 1 2))
 3
```

docs: [racket quote](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/quote.html)

Answer (score 0):

`+` is bound to a procedure in most scopes, but is itself a symbol. The procedure to which it is almost-always bound is a procedure.
For instance, in
`(let ((+ "+")) +)`, `+` is a string. In any reasonable state, you'll have something like

`(procedure? '+)
=> #f
   (procedure? +)
=> #t`,
all of which is to say, in most programming languages you can imagine the environment of available variables/functions/etc as a dictionary of symbols to values, it's just that in scheme the symbols which point to the values are accessible as values. So in quoting the list `(+ 1 2)`, you refer to a list of symbols, the keys in the environment/dictionary, instead of the values.
`(symbol? (cadr '(1 + 2)))`
versus `(procedure? (cadr (list 1 + 2)))`